# ubuntu Run script with parameter - as keyboard shortcut gnome

Tags: bash, shell, parameters, keyboard-shortcuts, gnome-shell

How to make a keyboard shortcut under gnome run a shell script with parameter ?

On terminal the following works fine:

```
sbv.sh 50%
```

It adjusts the volume of a speaker.  The path of the script is /usr/bin.

But when entered as a command for keyboard-shortcut, neither

```
/bin/bash sbv.sh 50%
/usr/bin/sbv.sh 50%
gnome-terminal -x sbv.sh 50%
```

nor

```
sh -c "sbv.sh 50%"
```

produce the desired volume-change.  The speaker goes mute instead.

If the shortcut is changed to

```
notify-send "hello"
```

that produces the notification message, so the keyboard shortcut works alright.

Answer (score 0):

you can call your script as follows

```
$ gnome-terminal -x /usr/bin/sbv.sh "50%"
```

I'm using ubuntu 20.04, so, `-x` parameter seems to be deprecated, If you are using the same version, you'll need to use `--` instead of `-x`.

Comment: Thank you. - The system is running Ubuntu 18.04 and the -- option is the one that should be used, as you rightly suggested. Unfortunately, as a keyboard shortcut the command does not produce desired behavior. Using quotation marks with the parameter avoids muting the speaker, but it does not adjust volume. Maybe you have another suggestion ?